# TFS - My PC has changed, and the workspace assigned to the source control has also

Tags: tfs

Recently I downloaded the application I was working on from TFS source control. I am now working on a new PC, and the default name for the workspace appears to be the name of the PC.
So where the code was checked out before on my previous PC, the source code indicates the code has been checked out by another user, and has been assigned the previous workspce.
How do I change the source code assignment to my new workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Try Opening up the Visual Studio command prompt and typing:

```
tf workspaces /updateComputerName:OLDCOMPUTERNAME /s:”addressoftfsserver”
```

You may need admin privileges, I'm not entirely sure.